# Memory leak when using deallocate on NSData's UnsafeRawPointer?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, memory-leaks, swift5

I'm currently testing my streaming app which I have ported from Android to iOS and during the endurance tests I noticed a small memory leak which I was finally able to track down. Only problem is I don't understand why it occurs. I'm relatively new to Swift so it may be obvious but maybe someone can explain this. Below you can find an example of how the memory leak can be reproduced

```
private class TestThread: Thread {
    override func main() {
        self.name = "TestThread"
        print("Started TestThread")
        repeat {
            let frameSize = Int.random(in: 523..<63453)
            let dataBuffer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: frameSize, alignment: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.alignment)
            let frameData = Data(bytesNoCopy: dataBuffer, count: frameSize, deallocator: .none)
            
            // The line below works fine, no memory leak
            //dataBuffer.deallocate()
            
            // Using the code below instead of the line above will result in a memory leak
            let pointer = (frameData as NSData).bytes
            pointer.deallocate()
            
            ThreadingUtil.sleep(ms: 5)
        } while !isCancelled
    }
}

// This is the ThreadingUtil.sleep method
public static func sleep(ms: UInt) {
    usleep(useconds_t(1000 * ms))
}
```

When you create and start the TestThread you can observe that the memory is slightly increasing over time and it will only be garbage collected once you stop the Thread. It seems the most part of the buffer's memory can be garbage collected but a small bit remains. I wonder why and why does it work fine when I deallocate the original UnsafeMutableRawPointer 'dataBuffer'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        let pointer = (frameData as NSData).bytes
        pointer.deallocate()
```

This is simply incorrect. You did not allocate `pointer`. You should not deallocate it.

There is no promise that the return of an `as` call is the same object as the original. `as` is not the same as a C-cast; it does not merely reinterpret a pointer. It can create copies, add bridging wrappers, etc. In this case it has to, since Data is not the same thing as NSData. They have different types with different structures.

```
import Foundation
var d = Data([0,1,2,3])
var data = d as NSData
print(type(of: d))  // Data
print(type(of: data)) // _NSInlineData
withUnsafeBytes(of: &d) { print($0) } // UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: 0x0000000100142100, count: 16)
withUnsafeBytes(of: &data) { print($0) } // UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: 0x0000000100142110, count: 8)
d.withUnsafeBytes { print($0) } // UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: 0x00007ffeefbffb50, count: 4)
print(data.bytes) // 0x0000000100304400
```

They're not the same memory. You can expand this example to larger data sizes, and you'll see different results (since the implementation details are different for different size blocks), but the basic point remains. You can't deallocate a pointer you don't own. And you don't own the `.bytes` pointer. It just happens to point to the same values as `dataBuffer`.

Note that there can be situations where this happens to work due to implementation details. The implementations of Data and NSData are pretty complex and both try to optimize things quite a lot (and particularly inline things quite a lot) so it is possible that an `as` conversion will be optimized away. You can't work this out by experimentation. You have to follow the memory management rules.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I already thought of something like that. My mistake was that I thought these are the same pointers and not two different pointers pointing to the same data. I work now with the UnsafeMutableRawPointer anyway so no problem anymore because this pointer is owned by me. I just wanted to understand what's going on, what I'm doing now thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

The "garbage collector" in swift is called ARC(Automatic Reference Counting) and it works a bit differently then the for example the java garbage collector.

ARC is basically counting references at runtime you can look more into it in [Swift Doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

> Every time you create a new instance of a class, ARC allocates a chunk of memory to store information about that instance. This memory holds information about the type of the instance, together with the values of any stored properties associated with that instance.

> Additionally, when an instance is no longer needed, ARC frees up the memory used by that instance so that the memory can be used for other purposes instead. This ensures that class instances don’t take up space in memory when they’re no longer needed.

Now before we look at reference counting of the function you need to understand that "UnsafeMutableRawPointer" doe's not provide automated memory management, so when you create "UnsafeMutableRawPointer" you need to remember to deallocate it for reference you can read about "UnsafeMutableRawPointer" [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer).

Let's look at the code:

```
private class TestThread: Thread {
    override func main() {
        self.name = "TestThread"
        print("Started TestThread")
        repeat {
            let frameSize = Int.random(in: 523..<63453) // frameSize memory allocation: 1
            let dataBuffer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: frameSize, alignment: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.alignment) // frameSize memory allocation: 0, dataBuffer memory allocation: 1
            let frameData = Data(bytesNoCopy: dataBuffer, count: frameSize, deallocator: .none)  // dataBuffer memory allocation: 1, frameData memory allocation: 1

            // Please note that if this line is commented dataBuffer will stay allocated in the memory until you specifically deallocate it yourself
            //dataBuffer.deallocate() 

            // pointer does not need to be specifically deallocated because as soon as you create it unlike the UnsafeMutableRawPointer class, it is deallocated by the ARC since you are not using it.
            let pointer = (frameData as NSData).bytes // dataBuffer memory allocation: 1, frameData memory allocation: 0
        
            ThreadingUtil.sleep(ms: 5)
        } while !isCancelled
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that UnsafeMutableRawPointer does not provide automatic memory management but that's exactly what I want. My mistake was that I thought the NSData.bytes is returning the same Pointer than dataBuffer's UnsafeMutablePointer which is not the case as far as I've understood according to the previous answer.  I agree that 'pointer' which is returned by NSData  must not be deallocated under normal circumstances but because I created frameData with 'deallocator: .none' I have to deallocate dataBuffer to release memory.